# Property 'foo' is missing in type 'X' but required in type 'Y'

Tags: typescript

I have the following piece of code:

```js
class Gateway {}
class GatewayA extends Gateway { open() {} }
class GatewayB extends Gateway { }

type UseCase<T> = (...gateways: Gateway[]) => () => Promise<T>;

const gatewayA = new GatewayA;
const gatewayB = new GatewayB;

const fooUseCase: UseCase<boolean> = (gatewayA: GatewayA, gatewayB: GatewayB) => async () => {
  console.log(gatewayA);
  console.log(gatewayB);
  return true;
};

fooUseCase(gatewayA, gatewayB);
```

Gateways inherits from Gateway base class and might add new methods. Also, use cases can have different gateway arguments, meaning `fooUseCase` will need `GatewayA` and `GatewayB`, but `barUseCase` could need `GatewayC`, for instance.

But TS is throwing this error:

```
Type '(gatewayA: GatewayA, gatewayB: GatewayB) => () => Promise<true>' is not assignable to type 'UseCase<boolean>'.
  Types of parameters 'gatewayA' and 'gateways' are incompatible.
    Property 'open' is missing in type 'Gateway' but required in type 'GatewayA'.ts(2322)
```

How can I define the `UseCase` type without previous knowledge of what implementations of gateway are going to get passed as arguments?

Thanks.

Comment: `UseCase` needs knowledge of what arguments it accepts, unless you'd like to allow `fooUseCase(gatewayB, gatewayA)` and get a runtime error if the implementation actually treats its `gatewayA` parameter like a `GatewayA` and calls its `open()` method.  Maybe you just want to *infer* that information instead of needing to *annotate* it?  If so you can write a helper function to do that, [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nr9OVw), and I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining. If not, then what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah I wanted to make sure every use case would have the same signature by using that type (expects Gateways as arguments for the decorator function, returning a function that returns a promise). Doing with generics and extends is the way to go, as you pointed out. Thanks

Comment: Well you already accepted another answer that only accepts exactly two inputs instead of being variadic, so I'm not sure what to do here.  Are you satisfied with the existing answer or do you want me to write one up?

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason is that `UseCase` is designed to work on any gateway, while the instance fooUseCase "forces" to pass a specific GatewayA.

Let's image a function `doSomeJob` that require a `UseCase` as parameter. Suppose this function has only 2 gatewayB's to supply to this use case. According to the contract, it should work. But it won't be able to be called properly with `fooUseCase`:

```
doSomeJob(fooUseCase);

function doSomeJob(useCase: UseCase<boolean>) {
    useCase(new GatewayB(), new GatewayB())
}
```

You can work around this with parameterized types:

```
type UseCase<G1 extends Gateway, G2 extends Gateway, T> = (gatewayA: G1, gatewayB: G2) => () => Promise<T>;

const fooUseCase: UseCase<GatewayA, GatewayB, boolean> = (gatewayA: GatewayA, gatewayB: GatewayB) => async () => { ... }
```

Comment: Now I understand the root issue here. Thank you a lot for the explanation.